# How to hold a for loop for some specific time of Period?

Tags: android

I want hold a for loop for specific time of period.

I was using `Thread.Sleep(duration)` But It is wrong.
 Please let me know any solution for this Problem. In advance Thanks for suggestion. If there is any concern please let me know.

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               //write here your code
            }
        }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`Handler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)**

```
for (int i = 0; i<50 ;i++) {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // perform your task here
        }
    }, 1000 );// delay time in miniseonds
}
```

Comment: This would hold each iteration for X milliseconds delay. I believe he wants to hold the whole loop for a certain time.

Comment: @riadrifai may be but he didn't inform about thats why i have gave this solution

Answer (score 0):

To hold `for loot` for a specific time : just copy past above snippet and try to change millisecond **1 second = 1000 millisecond**

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i=0;i<50;i++){
                    tvOutput.setText(i+"\n");

                }
            }
        },1000);  //time in millisecond
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int x= 5;                       // this condition is given as an example
 for(int i=0 ; i<=50 ;i++){

    if(x==5){                       // this condition is given as an example

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   // what you want to do
                }
            },1000);  

       }
    }
```

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes i will keep this in mind and also i have edited above